# Delete Confirmation alert in jQuery Mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile

i am working on jQuery mobile in Rails.
I have a link like

```
<a class="btn btn-info message-delete-action" data-link-url="/messages/{{id}}/delete" href="#">Delete</a>
```

I am trying to add a alert confirmation on clicking delete

Please suggest some solution.
I have tried with `data-rel="popup"` but i am not getting any popup

Comment: I'm guessing you want to use JQM's popup and not the regular javascript `confirm alert`, can you post your markup? Also be aware that the `popup` is only in the JQM 1.2 **Alpha** and not in the latest stable release (1.2).

Comment: @Jack Yes jQM'popup only i am expecting.<a class="btn btn-info message-delete-action" data-link-url="/messages/{{id}}/delete" href="#" data-rel="popup"> Delete</a>

Answer (score 0):

Based on your markup I think you may have misunderstood how the [JQM popup widget](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/popup/index.html) works. The way it works is first of all you need to provide markup for the popup

Something like this for your popup markup (taken from the docs)

```
<div data-role="popup" id="deleteConfirm" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" style="max-width:400px;" class="ui-corner-all">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
                <h1>Delete Page?</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
                <h3 class="ui-title">Are you sure you want to delete this page?</h3>
                <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>    
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b">Delete</a>  
            </div>
        </div>
```

And then on your link you need to either reference the `id` of your popup like

```
<a href="#deleteConfirm" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop">Delete</a>
```

Or you can also call the popup programmatically like `$('#deleteConfirm').popup("open")`

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/simpledialog/latest/jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.js

will provide a plugin that helps to have confirmation popups

Comment: the question was how, not which tool - you might consider explaining how the plugin is working

Comment: @kleopatra http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/ explains how the plugin is working

Comment: you can edit your answer with the additional info - though note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.